# Unmirroring OpenTok video Input

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

I am using OpenTok for video conferencing in my app. I want to un-mirror my publisher video so that the person at other end can read text (as right now its a mirror image). OpenTok playground provides this feature but I am unable to find sample code for the same.

Comment: Are subscribers to your stream seeing the video mirrored?  The default behavior is have the publisher video mirrored, but not subscriber video, so that reading text shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment states, subscribers should always see the video the right way around. Only the publisher's video is mirrored so they can see themselves in a natural way. If you want the publisher's video not to be mirrored then initialise the publisher like this:

```
const publisher = OT.initPublisher({ mirror: false });
```

Please see documentation for the `mirror` property here: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#initPublisher

Comment: yes you are right i was using custom video input for the publisher and was mirroring that input. The default openTok settings allows to read the text.